# Lwjgl terrain rendering using x,y,z coordinates without using heightmap

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Lot of resources are available online to generate terrain from Heightmap image using Lwjgl
but I researched for a long time and I haven't find any resources to generate terrain from x,y, and z values from textfile without using heightmaps,,these x,y and z values represents a single vertex (x,z, and height information)...

Suggest me some resources for developing terrain from x,y,z coordinates using lwjgl

Answer (score 1):

*Arbitrary and unstructured point data has to be converted in some way*

The simplest way is to have a height map already. If you do not have this you are confronted with a point cloud. Either you need to map it into a height map or resolve the surface under it.

[Generating surface from point cloud](https://www.google.com/search?q=generaing+surface+from+point+cloud)

[AutoCad Implementation](http://docs.autodesk.com/MAP/2013/ENU/index.html?url=filesMAPUSE/GUID-B60FBD85-AB5E-4A20-86BF-8A2D6F5D6746.htm,topicNumber=MAPUSEd30e118676)